# DataStage Parsing Input String to Date Format

Tags: datastage

I have a string input format of i.e

```
 'Thu, 30 Nov, 2017'
```

I need to transform this into a more Oracle database friendly Date type format of something like '11-30-2017' or '11/30/2017'.  I started in the path of

```
Convert(' ','-',Convert(',','',DSLink.InputDate[5]))
```

which should return a string of:  `30-Nov-2017`

However I'm stuck on dynamically parsing the `'Nov'` month part.  Any clever ideas?

also I don't think this will work:

```
StringToDate(Convert(' ','-',Convert(',','',DSLink.InputDate[5])),"%dd-‌​%mm-%yyyy")
```

as the function is looking for a numeric type on the month field?

Comment: Have you tried StringToDate function using the format string described here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_date_Formats.html  This includes %mmm with stands for Nov etc.

Comment: I missed the '%mmm', thank you for this!

Comment: If my comment solved your problem please upvote it

Comment: Not sure how to vote a comment? You can answer it and I'll up vote it.

Comment: Answer or good information is valuated by clicking the arrow on the left of the comment or answer - this increases the reputation - this is how this forum works :-)